# How to use arguments with 'find -exec'?

Tags: shell, find, io-redirection

I'm trying to generate static html files for all php scripts inside dir:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec php {} > {}.html \;
```

But it just dumps all results to `{}.html`. How to do it properly? And how to remove '.php' from filenames?

Comment: same question: http://superuser.com/q/604000/4714

Answer (score 7):

This should be the more efficient still portable way:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sh -c \
   'for i; do php "$i" > "$(dirname "$i")/$(basename "$i" .php).html"; done' sh {} +
```

or the simpler and even more portable thanks to Stephane Chazelas' comments:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sh -c \
   'for i do php "$i" > "${i%.*}.html"; done' sh {} +
```

The latter also fix the odd directory name issue Stephane noted.

Comment: +1 for learning something about basename. But why `for i` and not `$1`? But is `-exec +` really more portable than bash (which doesn't need `dirname` and `basename`)...?

Comment: What is non portable (I mean non POSIX here) in the other replies so far is the use of non isolated `{}` in find exec clause, `xargs -i` is non portable although `xargs -I {} ` would be, `rename ` is non portable as not specified by POSIX, `shopt` is bash specific. On the other hand, `-exec +` is definitely portable as specified by POSIX.

Comment: `for i; do` is not standard. `for i do` is. `${i%.*}` is POSIX and not Bourne just like `$(...)`. That code assumes directory names don't end in newline characters.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the tips, answer updated.

Comment: @Hauke I used `for i` and not `$1` as the shell is passed multiple arguments given the `-exec +` ending.

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
find . -name "*.php" | sed "s/\.php//" | xargs -i sh -c 'php "{}.php" > "{}.html"'
```

Comment: This does not work when the filenames have newlines in them.

Comment: That doesn't work for all sorts of file names and is very dangerous just like @HaukeLaging's one.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is a very readable solution:

```
shopt -s extglob
rename --no-act --verbose 's/php$/html/' /path/to/parent/dir/**/*.php
```

Remove `--no-act` if it looks OK.

Comment: It's the `globstar` option you want for `zsh`-style recursive globbing in `bash`. Note that `bash`'s `**` (contrary to zsh's, ksh93's or tcsh's) follows symlinks.